# Can you add html meta-description to django blog post model?

Tags: html, django, django-models, meta-tags

I'm wondering if it's possible/google allows to add a meta_description CharField to Post model to  dynamically change meta description on html page?

My current meta description is

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ post.title }} blog post from the {{ post.category }} category.">
```

Which obviously isn't ideal as it doesn't give a great description of the individual blog post. Then I got to thinking of whether I can just add a field to set in the same manor. This way I would be able to set the CharField to max length so I know all meta descriptions are proper length, and I would be able to set a proper description for each blog post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length =250)
   body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
   meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=150)


<meta name="description" content="{{ post.meta_description }}"
```

- Does anyone see any issues with this before I attempt to implement it?
- Does anyone know if this is allowed by Google?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [blocks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) instead of create new `meta description` field especially for that and this allowed by Google...

In your **base.html**:

```
<head>
     ...
     ...
    {% block metadescription %}
        <meta name="description" content="This site provide something...">
    {% endblock %}

</head>
```

and your **post_detail.html**:

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}

{% block metadescription %}
    <meta name="description" content="{{post.description|truncatechars:25}}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   ....
{% endblock %}
```

---

**Updated** answer for below comment:

Here you can use class `property` and pass this property in `context`..

**models.py**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length =250)
   body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def convert_in_meta(self):
        title = (self.title)[0:50]
        body = (self.body)[0:100]
        description = title + str(body)
        return description
```

**views.py:**

```
def post_detail(request,pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id = pk)
    post_meta = post.convert_in_meta
    return render(request,"post_detail.html",{'post_meta':post_meta,...})
```

Comment: I do already use blocks for the rest of the site, and for the current posts, as shown in original post I am currently using post.title and post.category to make the meta description. I don't have a field description for each post, only title, body, category, and tags. 
I suppose I could try and use body and truncate the chars, and just try to make sure each blog post has a descriptive first 150 characters, but I thought it might be easier to make a new field and use that. What do you think is best solution?

Comment: @LBJ33 Use class `property` and pass this in `context` instead of create new field for this...See my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932117/14131913) above.